# Clear Binding in FrameworkElement in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, code-behind

**Background**

I am creating a new control that inherits from `TextBox` that wraps the `Binding`. Basically so you can create a `TextBox` that has a single `ValidationRule` without the extra code required in XAML. So instead of:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="DisplayWidth"
                 Converter="{StaticResource DistanceUnitConverter}">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <valid:DoubleValidationRule/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

It would be simplified to:

```
<ctrls:ValidateConvertTextBox BindingPath="DisplayWidth"
                              ValidationRule="{StaticResource DoubleValidationRule}"
                              ValueConverter="{StaticResource DistanceUnitConverter}"/>
```

The reason for this is because I have a bunch of these all over the place and I cannot create a template that uses something like:

```
 <Binding Path="{TemplateBinding Path}">
     ...
 </Binding>
```

Because Path is not a DependencyProperty.

**Question**

In the code behind, when I try to create this new Binding, I have the 3 dependency properties shown above in the XAML and something like this:

```
private void SetBindingPath( string value )
{
    if( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( value ) ) return;

    Binding = new Binding( value );
    SetBinding( TextProperty, Binding );
}

private void SetValidationRule( ValidationRule value )
{
    if( Binding != null )
    {
        Binding.ValidationRules.Clear();
        Binding.ValidationRules.Add( value );

        SetBinding( TextProperty, Binding );
    }
}

private void SetValueConverter( IValueConverter value )
{
    if( Binding != null )
    {
        Binding.Converter = value;
        SetBinding( TextProperty, Binding );
    }
}
```

And I was wondering if calling `SetBinding` will create three `Bindings` on `TextProperty` or since they will all be the same reference to `Binding` I do not have to call `SetBinding` three times? Also, if the `BindingPath` property was changed (so `Binding` now points somewhere else, do I need to "unregister" the previous binding before resetting it again? And if so how to do that. I couldn't find anything that sounded right in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you looking for is this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748951.aspx

```
BindingOperations.ClearBinding(myText, TextBlock.TextProperty);
```

Also take a look at this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.clearallbindings.aspx

Answer (score 0):

BindingOperations.ClearBinding(yourTextBox, TextBlock.TextProperty);